# Remove an item from Hidden Div via Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a Table structure

```
   <table id='dataTable'>
       <tr>
        <td class="dataLabel">
            <div style="display:none" class="hours_logged">
                <div class="time_item">
                    <div class="record_id">34</div>
                    <div class="time_logged">2</div>
                    <div class="desc">Another Time Added</div>
                </div>
                <div class="time_item">
                    <div class="record_id">37</div>
                    <div class="time_logged">3</div>
                    <div class="desc">New Time Added</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove div class"time_item" which contains record_id "37"

This is what i am trying

`$('table#dataTable div:contains("37")').parent().remove();`

Comment: It seems you've misspelled parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [:has-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) or [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('#dataTable div.time_item:has(div.record_id:contains(37))').remove()
$('#dataTable div.time_item').has('div.record_id:contains(37)').remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6wwmB/)

A more accurate solution will be

```
$('#dataTable div.time_item').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).find('.record_id').text()) == '37';
}).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ZfkM/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table#dataTable div:contains('34')").parent().remove();
```

or

```
var containsVal = "34";
$('#dataTable div.time_item:has(div.record_id:contains('+ containsVal+'))').remove();
```

Comment: Hey harshboss and Arun P Johny  answer was correct, i tried and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ID's, for performance purposes it's good to use them in your HTML:

```
<div class="time_item">
    <div id="record_37" class="record_id">37</div>
    <div class="time_logged">3</div>
    <div class="desc">New Time Added</div>
</div>
```

Then with jQuery

```
$('#record_37').closest('.time_item').remove();
```